# Same mysql queries in two similar databases in the same machine have different perfomance

Tags: mysql, database

I have two databases one for dev and one for staging, and they're both on the same machine too. I'm having a problem with a query for two tables. here are the schema for the tables

Table 1 schema:

```
Table: import_schedule_t
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `import_schedule_t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `theater_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pc_url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `mb_url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `url_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `intime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `utime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `schedule_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `movie_name` text NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and Table 2 schema:

```
 Table: wp_postmeta
 Create Table: CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
   `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `meta_value` longtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
   KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
   KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1399270 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

both of the tables are present in both of the databases i've mentioned. When i try to run this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT movie_code,post_id 
 FROM import_schedule_t 
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
 ON wp_postmeta.meta_value = import_schedule_t.movie_code 
 AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='update_movie_id' 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d')>= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

dev database would finish the query in 20 seconds but the staging database would only run it for 1.4 seconds.

here's a sample data:
wp_postmeta table

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value |
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+
|   45150 |   74572 | update_movie_id | 74572      |
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+
```

import_schedule_t table (omitted some of the fields)

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id     | movie_code | start_time          | end_time            |
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 120884 | 74572      | 2015-07-04 12:50:00 | 2015-07-04 15:05:00 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

i already tried looking at the indexes and optimizing the tables but with no success, the query time on the dev database is still 20 seconds.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED on dev

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | import_schedule_t | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   23597 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_postmeta       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1461731 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED on staging

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | import_schedule_t | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    9311 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_postmeta       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1461384 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: please untag 'sql server'

Comment: Are you running the same version of MySQL on both servers? Perhaps there is a large difference in the amount of data on the tables? Your queries look okay to me. I do think that formatting the date for a where clause is unnecessary. start_time >= date_time should work just as well.

Comment: well yeah basically the same version, cause they're on the same machine.  the difference in data size doesn't seem to be the cause as both database contain 1.3m records. Im still looking at the index tho. noted the date_format, thanks

Comment: Could you run an EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the queries and show us the results please. I'm not entirely sure of this one, but it may help to move your wp_postmeta.meta_key='update_movie_id'  out of the ON clause and into the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

If both DBs are running on the same machine, with the same MySQL version, in the same harddrive, with the very same structure and data then it might be a fragmentation issue on the OS level. Take the servers down and defrag your disk.

On a side note: don't compare dates as strings, since dates are numbers internally in the DB, and they are compared much more efficiently (WHERE start_time >= curdate() ).
Also you can save some storage space if you define smaller ints for some fields (like the 'active' field). An int is a 4 byte number while a tinyint is 1 byte.

Comment: hmmm ok then ill ask the dc staff if there's an issue on the OS Level. noted the curdate().

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment cos I don't have enough reputation, BUT, I would expect the dev system has a lot more data in its tables.

On another point you should not use DATE_FORMAT - I would guess that is turning your dates into strings which are really inefficient to compare. Dates are just integers (internal to MySQL) so they can be compared in one cycle.. the string comparison could easily be 1000 (or more) cycles. You should probably index the start_time field as well to save it having to scan the table.

Anytime you have a query taking 20 seconds you should be suspicious you are doing something wrong! MySQL can do A LOT in 20 seconds.